# Error while installing PostGIS on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: postgis

This is my first practice on Ubuntu machine. Here i am trying to install PostGIS 2.1 on postgresql server 9.3.2. When i am following the procedure mentioned here

[Help](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt)

I am getting the following error messages on the terminal window.

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pgagent : Depends: libkrb53 (>= 1.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8a-1) but it is not going to be installed
 postgis : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: liblwgeom-2.1.1 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Expecting some hints from anybody to resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you know what a dependency is?

Comment: Did you try the graphical installer for Ubuntu? Last headline on this page: http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: @Spießbürger all documents suggest avoiding the EnterpriseDB graphical installer for Ubuntu...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to disable the ubuntugis-unstable repository or the postgresql repository. Both will not work together.