# Conflicts while installing postgresql9.3-postgis2.1,QGIS and gdal-bin

Tags: qgis, postgis, gdal, installation, ubuntu

I want to use postgresql9.3-postgis2.1 and gdal-bin parallel .

I have refer instruction [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt) for installing postgresql-9.3 on ubuntu 12.04.
I have install qgis from [here](http://www.digital-geography.com/installing-qgis-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/#.U_jqH1QvktM)

While installing gdal-bin it will remove postgis. As I explore I found similar [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81241/error-while-installing-postgis-on-ubuntu-12-04) which says ***ubuntugis-unstable repository and postgresql repository will not work together***.

[image]

Then how can install postgresql9.3-postgis2.1 and gdal-bin parallel. Can someone help to solve the problem , Any suggestion will be great help for me.

Thanks

Comment: ubuntugis-unstable has packages for postgresql 9.1, gdal 1.10 and qgis 2.4. Is there any reason you need postgresql 9.3?

Comment: Hi Andre, I want use [json_parse](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) . which is not available in 9.1. Thanks

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.3 is available via ubuntugis for Ubuntu 14.04, but the geos package is still missing for that platform. So self-compiling seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed postgis by configure using source.

Download the latest PostGIS source and compile it

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar xzvf postgis-2.1.0.tar.gz 
cd postgis-2.1.0
./configure

make
checkinstall
```

For more details [visit](http://iocast.github.io/blog/2013/11/11-ubuntu-pgsql-posgis-and-plr.html) , Thanks

Comment: That's not the latest. The latest is postgis-2.1.3. Latest stables are listed here: http://postgis.net/source